# Entity framework: map an existing View in a SQL server or recreate the view through LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm in the process of creating a piece of software that processes data on an existing SQL Server database (which I can't change).
I'm using visual studio to develop my application in C# using WPF and the MVVM framework. 
Essentially, the main purpose of my program is to gather data from the several tables of the database and present it to the user in a meaningful way. I don't want to simply display the data in the tables, but instead to gather information spread over several tables and aggregate in a certain way.
For that purpose, I've already created several Views in the database (using SMSS), some of which are rather complicated.

My question is: should I map those Views in Entity Framework and use the created POCO class as the source of a Datagrid, or should I recreate those Views through a LINQ query? Secondly, can I use a list of anonymous type as the source of a datagrid, taking into account that it would, naturally, be read-only?

Thanks

Comment: Linq vs db view comes down to requirements. There may be performance gains in having a view defined on the database, but personally I don't like putting business logic (which a view could be considered to be business logic) into the database - I prefer that to be in my application. If there are multiple applications accessing the database directly that need the same information, a view would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if your views have no performance issues, you should map views to POCO. You do not need to recreate the wheels.

Secondly, you can bind a collection of anonymous type to source of a DataGrid, but anonymous type binding has a limitation of automatic column generation.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!